# How Can I Generate Similar Content Based On A Text File (60k characters)

Tags: python, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence

I want to generate content, but from a big file instead of a one-liner prompt.

My file contains 60k characters.

Is there an AI library like GPT-3 that can take big files and generate similar content ?

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the file?

Comment: It's a book. I have it as a text file. It is confidential but I can say it's about relationships, written in english.

Answer (score 2):

You could try fine-tuning GPT-2 to fit your needs. See [this article](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-fine-tune-gpt-2-so-you-can-generate-long-form-creative-writing-7a5ae1314a61). Alternatively, if you don't need anything particularly complicated or sophisticated, which doesn't gneerate very coherent sentences, you could use Markov chains with [`markovify`](https://github.com/jsvine/markovify) and [`spacy`](https://spacy.io/):

```py
import markovify
import spacy

FILE = "book.txt"

with open(FILE, "r") as file:
    book = file.read()

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm")
doc = nlp(cleaned)
sentences = " ".join([sent.text for sent in doc.sents if len(sent.text) > 1])
generator = markovify.Text(sentences, state_size=3)

output = ""

for _ in range(100):
    output += generator.make_sentence() + " "

print(output)
```

Make sure to run `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm` before you run this.

Comment: Thank you, but I have an error : bin/python3: No module named spacy when running the command

Comment: You need to install `spacy` with `python -m pip install spacy`.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a look to classic text generation notebook like this from tensorflow wich starts from Shakespeare corpus:

https://www.tensorflow.org/text/tutorials/text_generation

Generally, I think that you are looking for training or fine tuning a model on the whole corpus and then generate text starting from one sentence.

Comment: i'll check that now, thank you